# Is it possible to make (a, a) a member of typeclass in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here's a code in Haskell:

```
class Fooable a where
    foo :: a -> a

instance Fooable (a, a) where 
    foo = ...
```

Code like this would not compile in traditional Haskell without `FlexibleInstances` extension. The error message would say:

```
Illegal instance declaration for ‘Fooable (a, a)’
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for ‘Fooable (a, a)’
```

The question is, is it actually impossible to make tuple `(a, a)` a member of any typeclass, since `each type variable appears at most once in the instance head`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There are no ways to directly enforce the relationship of `(a, b)` in an instance (without `FlexibleInstances` or other extensions), but they may be equivalent.**

This means that if `Fooable (a, b)` is an instance, then if `a` can equal `b`, `Fooable (a,a)` is also an instance. Consider as gaining more instances.

However, there is somewhat of a way around:

```
newtype Tuple a = Tuple {unTuple :: (a, a)}

instance Fooable (Tuple a) where
    foo = id
```

It's not the prettiest or nicest thing on the planet, but at least at runtime it will behave as if there were no wrapper.

Comment: Are you sure? If I enable `FlexibleInstances`, and define an instance on `(a, a)`, I can get it to work (e.g. `foo (x,y) = (x * 2, y * 7)` with the instance restricted to `Num a`). I can then use `foo` on values of type `(Int, Int)`, but not `(Int, Float)`.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden That's with `FlexibleInstances`, which is a GHC specific extension, not vanilla Haskell. Besides, the question seems to rule out the extension anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use other extensions instead, you can write

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
-- and/or
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

instance a ~ b => Fooable (a, b) where
  foo (a, b) = (b, a)
```

This will make `Fooable (a, a)` an instance, and ensure that no other pairs can be instances (without `OverlappingInstances`). [AJFarmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594037/1477667) has a rather more pleasant feel to it, however.

Comment: Isn't that an extension? I had certainly forgotten about that!

Comment: @AJFarmar, it certainly is an extension, as the first line says!

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on it when I search for Type Equality, only the package?

Comment: @AJFarmar, you can win that particular constraint with either `GADTs` or `TypeFamilies`. The type-level version, `:~:`, comes from `Data.Type.Equality` (re-exported by `Data.Typeable`).